# how to show data from Listview in Textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a Phone Book application.

I have a listview in which you can view the saved data in the database. I want to add an edit option.

More specifically: When I mark a row in the table with subscribers and phone numbers and hit the Edit button a window with two text boxes is shown on the screen. In the first text box is the name and in the second - a phone number of the marked entry.

Can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this...

> Yes, but TextBox and ListView are in different windows and I cannot
>   access it each other

in form2 drag and drop two textboxes and do like this....

Just create a property on the Form2 class and set it before you show Form2.

```
public class Form2
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return textbox1.Text; }
        set { textbox1.Text = value; }
    }
    public string phonenumber
    {
        get { return textbox2.Text; }
        set { textbox2.Text = value; }

    }

 }

public class Form1
{

  private void btnedit_Click(object sender, eventargs e)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < lv.Items.Count; i++)
      {
        // is i the index of the row you selected?
        if (lv.Items[i].Selected == true)
        {  
          //I show here the second field text (SubItems[1].Text) from the selected row(Items[i]) 
                Message.Show(lv.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
                break;
        }            
      }
      Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
      frm2.Name= text1;
      frm2.phonenumber = text2;
      frm2.Show();
      this.Hide();  //// if you want to hide the form1
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it will helps you....

Comment: I did it and compile it without problems but when I hit the Edit button I'm getting exception: "InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index" for this line 
`string number = listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;`

Comment: @Владислав Найденов  I have edited my answer take a look at my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the error. I change the values of SubItems indexes and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

use MouseClick Event for example,

```
private void ListBox1_MouseClick(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)  
{    
    this.TextBox1.Text = this.ListBox1.SelectedItem;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but TextBox and ListView are in different windows and I cannot access it each other.

Comment: if the textbox controls only in another form, or you have to declare a constructor in the form where the textbox, which pass the parameters selected in the listview from the main form, or otherwise declare the properties and enhance them with the selected item.